# FolderItem.Name does return name without file extension

Tags: powershell, windows-shell

1. Create file, lets say at `C:\randomname\file.txt`,
2. Now run the following script via PowerShell:

   ```
   $shell = new-object -com shell.application  
   $folder = $shell.NameSpace("C:\randomname")  
   $folder.Items() | where {$_.Name -eq "file.txt"}
   ```
3. Observe no output is produced which is rather unexpected.

Any idea how to resolve this situation in a reasonable manner other than modifying Windows settings?

**EDIT:**

To prevent confusion, this is just a stripped down version of my actual problem. Reason why I am using `shell.application` and not `Get-ChildItem` is that my `randomname` folder is actually zipped, i.e. I have `randomname.zip` and my actual code looks like this:

```
$shell = new-object -com shell.application  
$zip = $shell.NameSpace("C:\randomname.zip")  
$folder = $zip.Items() | where {$_.Name -eq "randomname"}
$folder.GetFolder.Items() | where {$_.Name -eq "file.txt"}
```

Comment: How is this related to [tag:vba]?

Comment: @RubberDuck from how I understand the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773938(v=vs.85).aspx), it seems like shell object can be used in both powershell and VBA so the behaviour is probably the same. Though it is just my guess, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Why are you using a `Shell.Application` object instead of `Get-ChildItem` in the first place?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers please see my updated question for explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`FolderItem.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787827(v=vs.85).aspx) return value depends on the value of particular Windows setting. Try the following:

1. Open Control Panel,
2. Folder Options, View tab,
3. Uncheck **Hide extensions for known file types**.

Re-run the script and you will see the expected output:

> Application  : System.__ComObject
>   Parent       : System.__ComObject
>   Name         : file.txt
>   Path         : C:\randomname\file.txt
>   ...

I was trying to write a portable script but after finding out how `Name` works this seems rather hard as I have no control over Windows settings of our customers and there is nothing like `FullName` for `FolderItem` so I can't figure out the reliable way out.

**EDIT:**

Based on suggestion from Nick Sedgewick, that `.Path` always returns filename with extension, unlike `.Name`, I was able to create a working workaround which does not depend on Windows settings and looks like this:

```
$shell = new-object -com shell.application  
$folder = $shell.NameSpace("C:\")  
$folder.Items() | where {(split-path $_.Path -leaf) -eq "file.txt"}
```

Comment: is there any reason why you cant use `get-childitem` instead of shell?

Comment: @Paul the reason is that the folder is not actually a folder but rather a .zip file with which `Get-ChildItem` is probably not able to work. I ll update my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

A Namespace Item has a PATH property, which returns full path and filename for files, and always includes the filename extension, whether the user has 'hide filename extensions' set or not.

So, use 'Path' instead of 'Name' and either write a function to pass  $_.Path  to which can the extract the filename part, or use an equivalent of the LIKE operator if there is one in powershell

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it pointed me in the right direction and I was finally able to fix the issue, see the **EDIT** section of my answer above. Sorry for not accepting yours, but it does not provide a working solution.